# How can I compile a program that uses subsitution file on RPG3 in as400?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I made a modification on a program which is already running in production and which uses file substitution.
I can't get it to compile because the file declaring as input has the same format name as another file.
This same input file is substituted by another at runtime and whose fields are used in the rest of the code for chain operations and as this one is not declared, these fields are not recognized :

```
 FFILELCT IF  E                    DISK
 F                                              KRECNO RCDNBR
 FEXTRPHOTO   E                    DISK                      A
```

This 2 files have the same format name ===> compilation errors
when the job is running : with wrkusrjob + 5 + option 15 I can see the file substitution FILELCT DB to file (XXXXXXXX/FILE2)

Would you have any solutions to make it compile?

Comment: Can you share some code and file description, I'm lost about which file is overriden or declared

Comment: FFILELCT IF  E                    DISK                      
 F                                              KRECNO RCDNBR                                                                      FEXTRPHOTO   E                    DISK                      A                                                                This 2 files have the same format name  ===> compilation errors                                                                              when the job is running  : with  wrkusrjob + 5 + option 15   I can see the file substitution   FILELCT         DB    to file (XXXXXXXX/FILE2)

Comment: Add the info to your question, not readable here, and comments are deleted

Comment: It may be that this is supposed to be compiled with a specific library list that points to the needed file whereas at runtime a different library list makes it get another file.  Alternatively, one might need to do a file override for the compile and not the run or vice-versa.  Not really a good practice either way.  There are keywords in RPG-IV like `EXTNAME` and `EXTDESC` that can let you make this more maintainable, but I am not sure if they are available to you.

Comment: it is writting in RPG 3. You mean I can create another input file withe different format name for the compile and then use the initial one for the run?

Comment: You say both files have the same **format** name ? Probably at last successfull compialtion there was a KRENAME line that you have to find

Comment: It would be very strange for a RENAME line to disappear....are you sure you're working from the source that matches what's in production?  Or did you add the second file?

Answer (score 1):

As @nfgl said, you need to use the K RENAME to rename the format for the second file. For the following code, I assumed that the name of the format is "ELCFMT". And I renamed the format to EXTRFM for the EXTRPHOT file.

```
 FFILELCT IF  E                    DISK                        
 F                                              KRECNO RCDNBR  
 FEXTRPHOTO E                      DISK                      A 
 F            ELCFMT                            KRENAMEEXTRFM
```

Comment: lots easier to deal with in RPG IV.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cvtRpgSrc` to create an ILE-Program first. Than try to compile again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by copying file1 into qgpltemp and renaming it with file name 2 then placing qgpltemp library first in the library list. Thank you all for the support